# Seeding function for database on ASP.NET Core that DOESN'T use EF

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I want to seed my database with test data but it looks as if the DbInitializer class requires a DbContext class or a class derived from DbContext.  So far I've learned ASP.NET through the tutorials which use EF.  Now I'm moving to a different ORM (Dapper) but I still want to seed my database with test data.  I tried googling "Seed database without using EF" and all the results are about using EF code first.  Is there a different class or method that I can use for this?

Comment: Just write some methods that use Dapper to insert seed data and wire it up in the same place that you would use DbInitializer. Does it need to be more complicated then that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dapper is just a wrapper around ADO.NET. It doesn't know anything about underlying tables, column types and relationships like EF. So, you cannot use DbInitializer for creating tables.

For seed, you could just execute a bunch of insert statements on application start using Dapper.